# How can I add Typescript support to a Quasar 2 project running on Vite?

Tags: typescript, vite, quasar-framework

The Quasar 2 documentation contains a detailed section how to use Typescript with Webpack:
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/supporting-ts

My Quasar project, however, uses the Vite configuration and I cannot find any useful information how to add Typescript support to an existing project.

Do you know where to find a setup guide or similar information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomment calculating the difference between an empty Typescript Quasar project, and an empty JS Quasar project, and apply it onto your project

To do that,

- Create a JS project in `/quasar-diff`
- Initialize `git` in that directory and commit everything
- Create a TS project in `/quasar-ts`, the same as JS one except using TS
- Delete all files in `/quasar-diff` except `/.git/` (using file explorer) (you may need to close editor for that)
- Copy all files from `/quasar-ts` to `/quasar-diff`
- Check uncommited changes to see the differences

Answer (score 0):

Quasar also has a doc page dedicated to `TS for Vite`: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/supporting-ts

Anyway, here is the result of `git diff -- .` after following Dimava's process

```
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintignore b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintignore
index f78c8ac9..6c702425 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintignore
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintignore
@@ -4,4 +4,5 @@
 /.quasar
 /node_modules
 .eslintrc.js
+/src-ssr
 /quasar.config.*.temporary.compiled*
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintrc.cjs b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintrc.cjs
index 046cbfdc..1c1e9b80 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintrc.cjs
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.eslintrc.cjs
@@ -4,13 +4,18 @@ module.exports = {
   // Remove this if you have an higher level ESLint config file (it usually happens into a monorepos)
   root: true,
 
+  // https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser
+  // Must use parserOptions instead of "parser" to allow vue-eslint-parser to keep working
+  // `parser: 'vue-eslint-parser'` is already included with any 'plugin:vue/**' config and should be omitted
   parserOptions: {
-    ecmaVersion: 2021, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
+    parser: require.resolve('@typescript-eslint/parser'),
+    extraFileExtensions: [ '.vue' ]
   },
 
   env: {
-    node: true,
     browser: true,
+    es2021: true,
+    node: true,
     'vue/setup-compiler-macros': true
   },
 
@@ -19,6 +24,10 @@ module.exports = {
     // Base ESLint recommended rules
     // 'eslint:recommended',
 
+    // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin#usage
+    // ESLint typescript rules
+    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
+
     // Uncomment any of the lines below to choose desired strictness,
     // but leave only one uncommented!
     // See https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/#available-rules
@@ -31,9 +40,12 @@ module.exports = {
   ],
 
   plugins: [
+    // required to apply rules which need type information
+    '@typescript-eslint',
+
     // https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#why-doesn-t-it-work-on-vue-files
     // required to lint *.vue files
-    'vue',
+    'vue'
     
   ],
 
@@ -62,16 +74,31 @@ module.exports = {
     'multiline-ternary': 'off',
 
     'import/first': 'off',
-    'import/named': 'error',
     'import/namespace': 'error',
     'import/default': 'error',
     'import/export': 'error',
     'import/extensions': 'off',
     'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
     'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
+
+    // The core 'import/named' rules
+    // does not work with type definitions
+    'import/named': 'off',
     
     'prefer-promise-reject-errors': 'off',
 
+    quotes: ['warn', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
+
+    // this rule, if on, would require explicit return type on the `render` function
+    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
+
+    // in plain CommonJS modules, you can't use `import foo = require('foo')` to pass this rule, so it has to be disabled
+    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
+
+    // The core 'no-unused-vars' rules (in the eslint:recommended ruleset)
+    // does not work with type definitions
+    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
+
     // allow debugger during development only
     'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
   }
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.gitignore b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.gitignore
index f1d913c8..147199f9 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/.gitignore
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/.gitignore
@@ -17,6 +17,10 @@ node_modules
 /src-capacitor/www
 /src-capacitor/node_modules
 
+# BEX related directories and files
+/src-bex/www
+/src-bex/js/core
+
 # Log files
 npm-debug.log*
 yarn-debug.log*
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/README.md b/ts_diff/quasar-js/README.md
index 7d49f77e..73c2b8cf 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/README.md
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/README.md
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-# Quasar App (quasar-js)
+# Quasar App (quasar-ts)
 
 A Quasar Project
 
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/jsconfig.json b/ts_diff/quasar-js/jsconfig.json
deleted file mode 100644
index 456944a5..00000000
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/jsconfig.json
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,39 +0,0 @@
-{
-  "compilerOptions": {
-    "baseUrl": ".",
-    "paths": {
-      "src/*": [
-        "src/*"
-      ],
-      "app/*": [
-        "*"
-      ],
-      "components/*": [
-        "src/components/*"
-      ],
-      "layouts/*": [
-        "src/layouts/*"
-      ],
-      "pages/*": [
-        "src/pages/*"
-      ],
-      "assets/*": [
-        "src/assets/*"
-      ],
-      "boot/*": [
-        "src/boot/*"
-      ],
-      "stores/*": [
-        "src/stores/*"
-      ],
-      "vue$": [
-        "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js"
-      ]
-    }
-  },
-  "exclude": [
-    "dist",
-    ".quasar",
-    "node_modules"
-  ]
-}
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/package.json b/ts_diff/quasar-js/package.json
index 4b08d38e..5f8a3fe5 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/package.json
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/package.json
@@ -1,12 +1,12 @@
 {
-  "name": "quasar-js",
+  "name": "quasar-ts",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "A Quasar Project",
   "productName": "Quasar App",
   "author": "Jean Claveau <jean.claveau@gmail.com>",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
-    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
+    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue ./",
     "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
     "dev": "quasar dev",
     "build": "quasar build"
@@ -18,15 +18,18 @@
     "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
+    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.0",
+    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.0",
     "eslint": "^8.10.0",
     "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
     "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
     "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
     "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0",
     "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
+    "@types/node": "^12.20.21",
     "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.3.0",
     "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
-    "postcss": "^8.4.14"
+    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
   },
   "engines": {
     "node": "^18 || ^16 || ^14.19",
diff --git a/ts_diff/quasar-js/quasar.config.js b/ts_diff/quasar-js/quasar.config.js
index 58038493..298db123 100644
--- a/ts_diff/quasar-js/quasar.config.js
+++ b/ts_diff/quasar-js/quasar.config.js
@@ -113,7 +113,7 @@ module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
     // https://v2.quasar.dev/options/animations
     animations: [],
 
-    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#property-sourcefiles
+    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#sourcefiles
     // sourceFiles: {
     //   rootComponent: 'src/App.vue',
     //   router: 'src/router/index',
@@ -175,7 +175,6 @@ module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
       // extendElectronMainConf (esbuildConf)
       // extendElectronPreloadConf (esbuildConf)
 
-      // specify the debugging port to use for the Electron app when running in development mode
       inspectPort: 5858,
 
       bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'
@@ -196,7 +195,7 @@ module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
       builder: {
         // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration
 
-        appId: 'quasar-js'
+        appId: 'quasar-ts'
       }
     },
```

We can already see here that the major config change concerns:

- eslint
- some imports in package.json
- jsconfig.json vs tsconfig.json

There also differences in the `src/` folder like (obviously)

```
-<script>
+<script lang="ts">
```

And some examples are slightly different